# Does instantiating more objects results in more instantiation of member functions?

Tags: c++

I think this should be something basic, but I can't find a good keywords to search for it.

If the same member function is instantiated more and more, would it be better, memory-wise, to move the function to a manager class?

Comment: No. It is a common implementation technique to invisibly (to you) pass in the `this` parameter to the non-static member functions as an argument - so no code is "generated" for each instantiated object (some thunks excluded).

Comment: @Niall Thanks for the link to the more comprehensive Q&A. Do you know what happens to the static member functions? do they silently get implemented as a global function in a namespace?

Comment: Something like that - they the same as other functions, but they don't get an "invisible" `this` and the compiler takes care of the scope/visibility and access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiation of objects only allocates memory for non-static data members of the object, not the member functions.

If you have two objects of a class, it doesn't mean that you also have two copies of the members functions of the class, instead [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) pointer is passed to the non-static member functions to specify that which object is calling the member function.

Comment: Do you know what happens to the static member functions? do they silently get implemented as a global function in a namespace?

Comment: No, we still have to use name of the class or object to access the class' static member functions, i.e. `MyClass::aStaticMemberFunction()`, just `this` pointer is not passed to the static member functions.